# Cannot resolve showQueston argument in getActivity().showQuestion inside my Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using activity class code to create a fragment of each. I was able to successfully change the Mainactivity class to main fragment with replacing this with getActivity() and adding view before each findmyID. 
But I'm not able to convert showquestion which highlights in red color although I added getActivity() before it replacing Mainactivity.this which was before.

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Here is the whole code

```
public class question extends Fragment {
EditText question = null;
RadioButton answer1 = null;
RadioButton answer2 = null;
RadioButton answer3 = null;
RadioButton answer4 = null;
RadioGroup answers = null;
Button finish = null;
int selectedAnswer = -1;
int quesIndex = 0;
int numEvents = 0;
int selected[] = null;
int correctAns[] = null;
boolean review =false;
Button prev, next = null;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, container, false);


    TableLayout quizLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.quizLayout);
    quizLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    try {
        question = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.question);
        answer1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.a0);
        answer2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.a1);
        answer3 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.a2);
        answer4 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.a3);
        answers = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.answers);
        RadioGroup questionLayout = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.answers);
        Button finish = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.finish);
        finish.setOnClickListener(finishListener);

        prev = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Prev);
        prev.setOnClickListener(prevListener);
        next = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Next);
        next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);


        selected = new int[QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()];
        Arrays.fill(selected, -1);
        correctAns = new int[QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()];
        Arrays.fill(correctAns, -1);


        this.showQuestion(0,review);

        quizLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
    }
    return view;
}


private void showQuestion(int qIndex,boolean review) {
    try {
        JSONObject aQues = QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().getJSONObject(qIndex);
        String quesValue = aQues.getString("Question");
        if (correctAns[qIndex] == -1) {
            String correctAnsStr = aQues.getString("CorrectAnswer");
            correctAns[qIndex] = Integer.parseInt(correctAnsStr);
        }

        question.setText(quesValue.toCharArray(), 0, quesValue.length());
        answers.check(-1);
        answer1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        answer2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        answer3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        answer4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        JSONArray ansList = aQues.getJSONArray("Answers");
        String aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(0).getString("Answer");
        answer1.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(1).getString("Answer");
        answer2.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(2).getString("Answer");
        answer3.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(3).getString("Answer");
        answer4.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        Log.d("",selected[qIndex]+"");
        if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
            answers.check(R.id.a0);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
            answers.check(R.id.a1);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
            answers.check(R.id.a2);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 3)
            answers.check(R.id.a3);

        setScoreTitle();
        if (quesIndex == (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()-1))
            next.setEnabled(false);

        if (quesIndex == 0)
            prev.setEnabled(false);

        if (quesIndex > 0)
            prev.setEnabled(true);

        if (quesIndex < (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()-1))
            next.setEnabled(true);


        if (review) {
            Log.d("review",selected[qIndex]+""+correctAns[qIndex]);;
            if (selected[qIndex] != correctAns[qIndex]) {
                if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                    answer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                    answer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                    answer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 3)
                    answer4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 0)
                answer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 1)
                answer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 2)
                answer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 3)
                answer4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}


private View.OnClickListener finishListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setAnswer();
        //Calculate Score
        int score = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
            if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i] == selected[i]))
                score++;
        }
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
        alertDialog.setMessage((score) +" out of " + (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()));

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Retake", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = false;
                quesIndex=0;
                getActivity().showQuestion(0, review);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Review", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = true;
                quesIndex=0;
               getActivity().showQuestion(0, review);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = false;
               getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }
};

private void setAnswer() {
    if (answer1.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 0;
    if (answer2.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 1;
    if (answer3.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 2;
    if (answer4.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 3;

    Log.d("",Arrays.toString(selected));
    Log.d("",Arrays.toString(correctAns));

}

private View.OnClickListener nextListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setAnswer();
        quesIndex++;
        if (quesIndex >= QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length())
            quesIndex = QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length() - 1;

        showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener prevListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setAnswer();
        quesIndex--;
        if (quesIndex < 0)
            quesIndex = 0;

        showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
    }
};

private void setScoreTitle() {
    getActivity().setTitle("SciQuiz3     " + (quesIndex+1)+ "/" + QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length());
}
```

}

Any help is well appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its private . . . change it to public

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali nope it didn't help either.

Comment: If `showQuestion()` is in the `Fragment`, why do you want to call it on the `Activity`? That is, why aren't you just calling `showQuestion()` directly?

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` returns `Activity`. So cast it before use.

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).showQuestion(...);
```

Make sure `showQuestion()` method is public in YourActivity.

Comment: but which activity should I replace with YourActivity I used ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showQuestion(0, review); but still the problem is same and showQuestion is highlighted in red colour.

Comment: YourActivity is activity where you add this `Fragment`.